# Is there a way to see all GCP Unlabelled resource?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My goal is to see all the unlabelled inventory so I can label them correctly and show it in cost tracking

Comment: Why do you need to do this? An instance belong to a project; Why adding a label to say the same thing?

Comment: I manage multiproject instances, and combine all the cost billing into 1 cost billing for the organization.

project-name is just an example, for example, I want to label it with the instance id, or with the instance type.

Currently my problem is how to label all unlabelled resource, so I might know what resource is not yet labelled, and where it belongs

Comment: I think that you should have a look to asset inventory feature to export the assets to BigQuery and then query exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding labels to all resources automatically is not possible, nevertheless, as other comment suggests, you could try to use [Asset inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/viewing-asset-history#getting_asset_history) for this purpose. You can also [export this to a GCP bucket](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-cloud-storage).

Comment: Thank you Ruben, this actually answered my question. This asset inventory help me to filter out the unlabelled resource

Answer (score 0):

To show all unlabeled resources you can use filter in gcloud command,

For example for show all unlabeled disks

```
gcloud compute disks list --filter=-labels:*
```

For compute instances use:

```
cloud compute instances list --filter=-labels:*
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not work for my on a Mac:

cloud compute instances list --filter=-labels:*

Did work for my on a Mac:

gcloud compute instances list --filter="-labels:*"